# how to make jenkins pipeline to run docker commands on remote server

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I have 2 ec2 instances
1st one: that hosts jenkins and docker, which builds an image from a jar file then pushes it to docker hub repo

2nd one: which will be my application server, which will contain docker that will pull this image from docker hub and run the container on the docker engine

Ive done the 1st part which I create the image and push it to docker hub

my question is how to execute a docker commands from the jenkins pipeline to the my application server to pull the image from docker hub and run it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution for my issue

i used **SSH Steps plugin** plugin on jenkins

and its written in the pipeline as follows:

```
    stage('run commands on remote server') {
        steps { 
            script {
                def remote = [:]
                remote.user = 'ec2-user'
                remote.host = 'public or private ip of the remote server'
                remote.name = 'ec2-user'
                remote.identityFile = 'path for your ec2 private key'
                remote.allowAnyHosts = 'true'
                sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'your command 1 here'
                sshCommand remote: remote, command: 'your command 2 here'
            }
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Jenkins SSH plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh/) to and add a build step to Execute shell script on remote host using ssh
[image]

Or run 
`ssh user@host "docker pull <image> && docker run <image>"`

Comment: thank you for the answer
this is perfect
but what im looking for is a plugin or something that i can use in a pipeline code

i may use the second option you proposed in the pipeline as sh cmd, but is it the best way to do it?

Comment: For this example is the best way to do it, as long as you keep the variables that you pass to the docker container in secrets. In my opinion, the best way to do it is to use docker-compose or kubernetes, It will stil execute the commands via ssh but you have a clear view of what is deployed when you look at the .yaml files. If this is production you should use one of thoes orchestration systems.